# Как воспроизводить другое видео после перезагрузки страницы?

Tags: html, html5

Есть сайт с видео в фоне. Нужно воспроизводить новое видео после перезагрузки страницы. Вот код html:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>JabraOne</title>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="id.ico" sizes="45x48">
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <script src="js/skel.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/init.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body class="loading">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <video autoplay="1" loop="" id="player">
      <source src="./vid/3.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <div id="overlay"></div>
    ....
  </div>
</body>
```

По умолчанию воспроизводится 3.mp4, нужно менять после перезагрузки например на 4.mp4, после следующей на 5.mp4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для решения Вашей проблемы есть два решения:

### JavaScript

Необходимо написать JS который будет устанавливать куку просмотра того или иного видео, и при повторной загрузке сайта менять на другую.
Пример:

```
// функции для работы с куками
function getCookie(name) {
    var matches = document.cookie.match(new RegExp(
        "(?:^|; )" + name.replace(/([\.$?*|{}\(\)\[\]\\\/\+^])/g, '\\$1') + "=([^;]*)"
    ));
    return matches ? decodeURIComponent(matches[1]) : undefined;
}

function setCookie(name, value, options) {
    options = options || {};
    var expires = options.expires;
    if (typeof expires == "number" && expires) {
        var d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + expires*1000);
        expires = options.expires = d;
    }
    if (expires && expires.toUTCString) {
        options.expires = expires.toUTCString();
    }
    value = encodeURIComponent(value);
    var updatedCookie = name + "=" + value;
    for(var propName in options) {
        updatedCookie += "; " + propName;
        var propValue = options[propName];   
        if (propValue !== true) {
            updatedCookie += "=" + propValue;
        }
    }
    document.cookie = updatedCookie;
}

function deleteCookie(name) {
    setCookie(name, "", { expires: -1, path: "/", domain: window.location.hostname });
}

// example
// setCookie("cookieName", "cookieValue", { expires: expireTime, path: cookiePath, domain: allowedDomain, secure: useOrNotHttps })

// setCookie("langsite", "ru", { expires: 30*24*60*60, path: "/", domain: "eshko.ua", secure: false })
// expires: in one month
// path: on all site
// domain: eshko.ua
// secure: use http

// Сам код:
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (getCookie('LastVideoIndex') > 0) {
        var newIndex = getCookie('LastVideoIndex') + 1;
        setCookie('LastVideoIndex', newIndex);
        $('source').attr("src", './vid/'+newIndex+'.mp4');
    } else {
        setCookie('LastVideoIndex', 3);
    }
});
```

### PHP

По сути тоже самое только использовать сесию для хранения данных. Вставить внутри HTML страницы файл пере назвать в PHP и настроить **.htaccess**.

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['lastVideoIndex']) && $_SESSION['lastVideoIndex'] > 0) {
    $_SESSION['lastVideoIndex']++;
} else {
    $_SESSION['lastVideoIndex'] = 3;
}
echo '<source src="./vid/'.$_SESSION['lastVideoIndex'].'.mp4" type="video/mp4">';
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Я бы взял простой способ через js и localstorage. Идея такова - если пользователь заходит впервые, то у него есть например переменная firstVisited которая равно 0 (false). После того как страница загрузилась и все ок, переменная меняется на 1 и **сохраняется в localstorage** откуда потом выгружается после перезагрузки страницы.

....

```
    var firstVisited = localStorage.getItem('firstVisited');
    var count = 3; // номер видео по умолчанию
    if (firstVisited == null){
       firstVisited = 1; // первый раз на странице
       // и потому стандартное значение в video не нужно даже менять
    }
    else {
       count = localStorage.getItem('countVideo'); // вытаскиваем номер видео
    }

    if (!firstVisited) { // если уже не первый раз на странице 
        // присваиваем новое видео элементу video
        $("#player").attr("src","./vid/"+(count+1)+".mp4"); 

        localStorage.setItem('countVideo',count+1); // и сохраняем видео
    } 
    else{
    // если же в первый раз то нужно пометить, что со следующего раза видео должны меняться
        localStorage.setItem('firstVisited',0); ,

    }
```

1 строчка на jquery, но это можно сделать и на js.
P.S. я понимаю, что нет тега js, но я предложил способ "влоб"